# SHCNE_RENAMEITEM not working

Tags: shell, winapi, event-handling

I want to handle ANY changes in 3 folders (user programs, common programs, downloads), so I'm subscribing to FS events like this:

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidlDownloads = ::ILCreateFromPath(env::FOLDER_Downloads().c_str());

    DWORD dwFlags = SHCNE_CREATE | SHCNE_DELETE | SHCNE_MKDIR | SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER |
                    SHCNE_RENAMEITEM | SHCNE_RMDIR | SHCNE_UPDATEITEM | SHCNE_UPDATEDIR;
    SHChangeNotifyEntry monitoredFolders[3];
    monitoredFolders[0].fRecursive = TRUE;
    monitoredFolders[0].pidl = pidlCommonPrograms;
    monitoredFolders[1].fRecursive = TRUE;
    monitoredFolders[1].pidl = pidlPrograms;
    monitoredFolders[2].fRecursive = TRUE;
    monitoredFolders[2].pidl = pidlDownloads;

    dwFSSubscriptionID_ = ::SHChangeNotifyRegister(hWnd_,
        SHCNRF_ShellLevel | SHCNRF_InterruptLevel | SHCNRF_NewDelivery,
        dwFlags, WM_FOLDER_UPDATED, _countof(monitoredFolders), monitoredFolders);

    if (dwFSSubscriptionID_ == 0)
    {
        LOGERROR << L"FS watchdog failed to start.";
    }
```

Unfortunately, on **some** machines no message is sent, when I rename files. When I tried to create/delete folders, it was sent, but not when I renamed them. On other machines everything seems to be working. Why?

Comment: What's different between the machines?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Unfortunately, I can't understand, what's different. Both of them (where the message is being sent and where it is not) are the same Win 8.1 x64. If I knew, it would be a half of the answer =)

Comment: How do you rename files?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov In both cases I do it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Do you have SHCNE_UPDATEDIR message when SHCNE_RENAMEITEM is absent?

Comment: Do you rename folder or file. In first case you must catch SHCNE_RENAMEFOLDER instead if SHCNE_RENAMEITEM.

Comment: On a side note, to get the PIDL of a system-defined folder, you should be using [`ShGetFolderLocation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762180.aspx) or [SHGetKnownFolderIDList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762187.aspx) instead of `ILCreateFromPath()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is no CSIDL for downloads in XP SP2.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I tried renaming folders and files with the same result. Will try to handle SHCNE_UPDATEDIR getting rid of SHCNE_RENAMEITEM.

Comment: @noober: That is because there is no system-defined Downloads folder in XP, it was introduced in Vista (as was the `KNOWNFOLDERID` API).

Comment: @DenisAnisimov It has been revealed, that if I use Explorer/F2, no event is sent. If I use Far Manager, Ctrl+L, F6 the event is always being posted. Maybe, some flushing issue...